# CSS nth child - First TD in each row, alternate color?

Tags: css

Hopefully I can explain what I am trying to do.

In a table. The first TD in each row should alternate color.

Is this possible using nth child?

Ive tried a few things, but cant seem to logically wrap my head around this one.

(trying to expand my horizons)

```
<tr>
  <td>#0068b3</td>
  <td>#fff</td>
  <td>#fff</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>#aebde1</td>
  <td>#fff</td>
  <td>#fff</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>#0068b3</td>
  <td>#fff</td>
  <td>#fff</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>#aebde1</td>
  <td>#fff</td>
  <td>#fff</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `even`/`odd` to alternate between `tr` elements and select the first child `td` element:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V2FwB/)

```
table tr:nth-child(even) td:first-child {
    background:#0068b3
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) td:first-child {
    background:#aebde1
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I was missing second half of your statements in the "td:first-child" portion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`tr td:first-child` should work.

Note: I first answered with nth-child for the tr because I could have sworn you asked for alternate row coloring...